# How to add variable value as a className in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to `javacript` . Here , I have following code

```
result.push(`<span class="mark">${str.substring(h.startOffset, h.endOffset)}</span>`);
```

Now, Here I have a variable `var className = "dymaicvale"` , Now I want to use that value in the span like instead of hard-coding the value `mark` want to use className . Can any one please help me with this ?

Comment: `<span class="${className}">${str.substring(h.startOffset, h.endOffset)}</span>`

Comment: You are doing for `str.substring` same way you can do for the class also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

you have variable `var className = "dymaicvale"` just put that variable here like this -

```
result.push(`<span class="${className}">${str.substring(h.startOffset, h.endOffset)}</span>`);
```

Hope this will work for you.